# " javax.servlet.* " and "HttpServlet" can't be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am new in Java EE Development.
I have installed **Java SE and JRE both 8u92** latest version and using **Eclipse JEE Neon version** for EE Development.
My **Tomcat Server 9 is running properly**, But whenever i am creating a new simple servlet project I am getting error related to libraries as above mentioned.
Kindly help me to figure out this.
Also,please tell me **instead of this can we use Java EE SDK 7?**, if so then how to connect it with Eclipse and Tomcat? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Goto Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries > Click
> New > Give Name as "Tomcat 9" > Click Ok > select "Tomcat 9" > click
> "Add External Jars" > "Go to tomcat lib path and select the jars
> required"
>
> Goto Project Properties > Goto Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > User Library >
> "Tomcat 9"

Comment: Thanks Bro, It works.